# How to define a multiple page ranges for pdftk with a bash variable

Tags: bash, pdftk

I'm using Arch linux, Openbox window manager, and bash.
Everything is up to date with the latest versions.

Can anyone tell me why I can't get the `"$page_range"` variable to show up within `pdftk` when I specify a couple of page ranges as `3-5 7-9`?

When I specify only one page range `3-5` in my yad pop-up box everything works as it should.

pdftk does allow more than one page range to be defined within the command. Indeed when I type the command out on the command line without using bash variables within it, pdftk works as expected taking the page ranges `3-5 7-9`. Just not when I contain this value within the variable `"$page_range"`.

All I want to do is extract page ranges 3-5 and 7-9 from file
/home/$USER/my_file.pdf
into another pdf file
using the variable `$page_range` to define my ranges.

Here is my simple script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# collect the values with yad

extract_values=$(yad --form --width=200 \
--title="Enter the page ranges you wish to extract" \
--text="\n\n  Enter the page ranges you wish to extract\n    as eg 301-302\n    or 301-302 305-306\n     for grouping" \
--field="Page range":text "11-13 21-23" \
--button="Cancel!gtk-close":2 \
--button="Edit script":1 \
--button="Submit":0)



# strip out the values from the string
page_range=$(echo $extract_values | cut -d '|' -f  1)
echo $page_range



# produce a unique file extender 
page_range_slugify="$(echo "$page_range" | sed 's/ /_/g')" 
echo;echo $page_range_slugify
echo


# specify the filename
f=/home/$USER/my_file.pdf

# get path and file name without pdf extension
fz="${f%.*}"

# check everything is as it should be
yad --text="\n page range = $page_range\n page_range_slugify = $page_range_slugify\n file + path without file extension = $fz\n\n"

# below works only for one range but will not expand for two page ranges
pdftk "$f" cat "$page_range" output "$fz"_"$page_range_slugify".pdf

# below takes one range only as above 
#pdftk "$f" cat "$(printf %s "$page_range")" output "$fz"_"$page_range_slugify".pdf

# below takes both ranges when ranges are directly placed within the command
#pdftk "$f" cat 3-5 7-9 output "$fz"_"$page_range_slugify".pdf
```

Comment: Have you try to use `3-5,7-9`

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are doing the right thing, you are quoting your variables. However, because they are quoted, that means the two ranges are passed as a single string to `pdftk` and it expects two or more strings separated by spaces. In this specific case, where you know and control what the variable's value is, you might be able to get away with no quoting. But not in all cases, and this looks like you're asking users for input so they could pass anything to the script, making that a security risk, so the clean solution is to use an array instead. Try this:

```bash
page_range=( $(printf '%s\n' "$extract_values" | cut -d '|' -f  1) )
```

You can then pass that as `"${page_range[@]}"` and have both the benefits of safely quoting your variables, *and* the ease of use of having multiple ranges in a variable.

So, the relevant lines in your script become:

```bash
page_range=( $(printf '%s\n' "$extract_values" | cut -d '|' -f  1) )

[ . . . ]
## With thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429887/1081936
page_range_slugify="$(IFS="_" ; printf '%s\n' "${page_range[*]}")" 

[ . . . ]
pdftk "$f" cat "${page_range[@]}" output "${fz}_$page_range_slugify".pdf
```

Comment: great answer. I will have a look again later

Comment: thank you. `"${page_range[@]}"` didn't work because the array had not been created. Added this in. Thanks very much for the encouragement in fixing this. Appreciation.

Comment: Oh man, sorry @kes, I forgot to add the parentheses. No need for the `read` call, simply changing `page_range=$(...)` to `page_range=( $(...) )` is enough. Fixed now.

Comment: thanks for the insight into using parenthesis to create arrays. I'm going to keep that in mind but use the more obvious, to me, `read -ra page_range <<< "$page_range"` so that I get more in the habit of using arrays. Because it's more spelled out. When I am using arrays more I will see your insight better & then be ready to move on to using parenthesis. I think if I use parenthesis now, when I look back & have forgotten I may wonder "what on earth is that".  I will consider going to parenthesis arrays immediatley & getting used to doing this to every string possible. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Kes you're welcome and of course, use whatever feels more natural to you!

Comment: interesting to discover that a string can be expanded into essentially what becomes a multi-variable array as seen by `pdftk`

Comment: @Kes this is not really about `pdftk` but about the shell and how it parses arguments. You can see this if you run `set -x` and then tun run a command. That will show how the shell is passing the arguments to the actual command run, and you will see it single quotes arguments to group them. That's why when you gave it `"$page_range"`, which had a value like `1-2 3-4`, it was passing `'1-2 3-4'` (a single string) while `pdftk` expected `'1-2' '3-4'` (two strings separated by a space).

Comment: thanks, I understood that through experimentation with `pdftk` by passing two separate page ranges `4-5` as `"$page_range_1"` and `7-8` as `"$page_range_2"` in one command and it worked. I followed your instructions for demonstrating this by looking at `set -x` with `foo="a b"` rendered as `$foo` and `"$foo"`, doing this both before and after issuing `set -x`, but it was not at all clear to me what `set -x` was showed. It did not stand out. I got the point anyway. Appreciate that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to **not** double quote the variable `$page_range`.
At least it gets the script working functionally.

ie
do this `$page_range`
not this `"$page_range"`

For some reason pdftk does not like `" "` expansion of that particular variable.

I was guessing that `pdftk` was eating one of the quotation marks and not the other at that position because of some bug which causes it to fail.
But that can't be that because
`page_range="3-5"` expands correctly as `"$page_range"` double quoted no space
but
`page_range="3-5 7-9"` **does not** expand correctly as `"$page_range"` double quoted

So it must be something to do with the space in the middle of the page ranges when double quoting and the way this is expanded or the way pdftk sees it.

Anyone any ideas?

Even if it is all now working without the quotation marks around  `$page_range` variable this is very odd.

Beause normally quotation marks around the variable in bash is safe. We are all used to doing this for the eventuality that a file path and name we are processing contains dreaded spaces!
It's thus very odd that not double quoting handles the spaces and quoting does not.
How strange.

Another thought is that space expansion may be to a particular type of space, in a particular character encoding format that pdftk does not like.

Comment: The problem is that when you quote, you present it as a single variable. You can watch this in action by running `set -x` and then `foo="a b"` and compare `echo $foo` with `echo "$foo"` . You will see that when you quote `"$foo"`, the `echo` command is given `'a b'` and not `'a' 'b'` which is what you would want for your `pdftk` case.